# Regex question - need to make sure I'm getting the right thing

Tags: regex

I need to parse a couple of name value pairs from line in a log file.

One  of the names is 'ruser=data' and another is 'user=data'.

Both will be on the same line.

How can I make sure that when I match 'user' I'm not getting the data for ruser?

Many thanks

Joe

Edit:

I'm using javascript, and I've tried:

```
var u = line.match(/user=\w+/);
var user = u[0].replace(/(^user=*)/, "");
var r = line.match(/ruser=\w+/);
var ruser = r[0].replace(/(^ruser=*)/, "");
```

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Joe, what language?  What is the regex you have tried?

Comment: What are the delimiters? Commas, semicolons, spaces, etc? For example is it "ruser=data,otherkey=data,user=data"

Comment: sorry, the delimiters are spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\buser=\w+/
```

and

```
/\bruser=\w+/
```

should work. `\b` is a word boundary anchor that only matches at the start/end of an alphanumeric "word".